# AppCompatActivity: manually add Toolbar or use a theme with ActionBar?

Tags: android, material-design

What is the difference between the two following approaches of having an action bar in an `Activity`?

**Manually use `Toolbar`**

Set the app's theme to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and then include a `Toolbar` manually into the layout like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

In code then use `AppCompatActivity`'s `setSupportActionBar()` method to use the toolbar.

**Use a theme with action bar**

Set the app theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (or any other theme with action bar) and don't include a separate `Toolbar` into the layout. In the debugger I can see that the resulting action bar is an `android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar`. Checking the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/96af432/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar.java) of it, I find that it at least "knows" about `Toolbar`.

My questions are:

In both cases I can use the Activity's callbacks to populate the actions, to get information about a tapped action/option etc. Also the visual appearance seems to be identical. Which makes me wonder...

- What is the correct approach?
- Is the theme based approach also using the `Toolbar` or is it something else?
- Advantages of either approach?

Comment: If you need to add toolbar in your activity, then you have to manually use toolbar

Comment: That's not true. The manually set toolbar acts an action bar because it is using `setSupportActionBar()`.